# Two almost identical queries, one works another doesn't, what's wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have 2 almost identical queries. One checks for posts before a certain time stamp another one checks for pts after a certain time stamps. However the one that is used for the future posts has all the necessary values  and is used to create a link to those events where is the one for the previous posts doesn't for some reason :(

Here is the code:

```
    $previous = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT MONTH(post_date) AS month, YEAR(post_date) AS year
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id =$wpdb->terms.term_id )
    WHERE ( $wpdb->posts.post_date < '$thisyear-$thismonth-01'
    AND $wpdb->terms.slug = 'events'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post')
        ORDER BY post_date DESC
        LIMIT 1");


$next = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT MONTH(post_date) AS month, YEAR(post_date) AS year
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id =$wpdb->terms.term_id )
    WHERE ( $wpdb->posts.post_date > '$thisyear-$thismonth-{$last_day} 23:59:59'
    AND $wpdb->terms.slug = 'events'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post')
        ORDER BY post_date ASC
        LIMIT 1");
```

Here is the code where those values are used:

```
    <tr>';

if ( $previous ) {
    $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="prev"><a href="' . get_month_link($previous->year, $previous->month) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__('View posts for %1$s %2$s'), $wp_locale->get_month($previous->month), date('Y', mktime(0, 0 , 0, $previous->month, 1, $previous->year)))) . '">&laquo; ' . $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev($wp_locale->get_month($previous->month)) . '</a></td>';
} else {
    $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="prev" class="pad">&nbsp;</td>';
}

$calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td class="pad">&nbsp;</td>';

if ( $next ) {
    $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="next"><a href="' . get_month_link($next->year, $next->month) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__('View posts for %1$s %2$s'), $wp_locale->get_month($next->month), date('Y', mktime(0, 0 , 0, $next->month, 1, $next->year))) ) . '">' . $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev($wp_locale->get_month($next->month)) . ' &raquo;</a></td>';
} else {
    $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="next" class="pad">&nbsp;</td>';
}

$calendar_output .= '
</tr>
```

SUMMARY :

WHAT'S WRONG?!

Comment: why are you adding time to one of the dates when you don't to the other? this is probably where your error is... `$thisyear-$thismonth-{$last_day} 23:59:59` do you need {} around $last_day? and do you need the time or just the date?

Comment: I prefer using `>= $thisyear-$nextmonth-01` keeps the code cleaner

Comment: Note that (with one exception) "LEFT JOIN x WHERE x" is the same as "INNER JOIN x WHERE x".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell from what is given, but my guess is that 'date' field type is strictly `date`, whereas in second query you are trying to use it as some kind of `datetime`. Like it can be `yyyy-mm-dd` but not `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. 
Another guess is that is something not SQL-specific, like `$last_day` is not set or string format is wrong etc.

Anyway, please consider two advices in future:

- Use MWE (Minimum Working Example). I am almost sure that if you cut out all them `JOIN`s and other stuff the error will still persist. So to say, just try to reduce it to `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ( $wpdb->posts.post_date > '$thisyear-$thismonth-{$last_day} 23:59:59'`.
- Second part of your code is, sorry to say this, of absolutely no use to tell what is wrong. It is obvious that if query returns no data, using this absent data will result in error. Would be much better to include raw result of first query and result/error of second one.

Comment: this answer is of no use as this was already specified in the comments 10 minutes prior